# Hypervisor SMP Issue

Tags: hypervisor, smp

previously thank you for read my Question.

I'm implementing 'SMP' work on my hypervisor project.

What i want to do is like bellow.

[image]

One virtual machine have two vcpus. And this Virtual Machine is working on 2 pCPU.

For example, one linux has 2 cpu as SMP.

Firstly, what i tried is set pc value as 0x80500000.
(zIamge is on 0x80500000 address)

when both pcpu run, pcpu0 works fine. but pcpu1 got a error like bellow.

[image]

It means 'prefetch abort' from Virtual Machine. and it's occurred when access level 3 as iss indicate 'f'.

I don't know how to access this problem to solve.

If you need any specific information, please tell me. i will add more information.

Please tell me any tips and check point to solve this.

Lastly, thank you.!!